# Trying to set up Plaid integration, can I use the Link library with ES6 module imports and exports syntax for non-React app?

Tags: javascript, typescript, stimulusjs, plaid

The Plaid quick start documention for link initialize has two examples: 1) in react using a node package called `react-plaid-link`

[image]

and 2) using plain Javascript with a CDN-loaded plaid-initialize script

[image]

I am writing a **non-React** app that uses ESBuild and Stimulus TS.  I would like to use the ES6 module imports and exports syntax for importing my Plaid functionality.

Is there a way to do this?

the node packages called `plaid` it appears to me does not contain frontend link initialize functionality, only backend functionality.

Essentially, what I am looking for is a node package for the frontend link initialize functionality, so that I could import it like so:

```
import Plaid from "plaid";
```

If I don't do this, I get a typescript error on this code

```
 var handler = Plaid.create({
...
```

**TS2304: Cannot find name 'Plaid'.**

Comment: Yes. React and Es modules are orthogonal. `import Plaid from "plaid";` is correct.

Comment: @AluanHaddad - this appears to give me the backend NPM for `plaid`, not the frontend link initialize object for Plaid. If I do this, I get a typescript error `Property 'create' does not exist on type 'typeof import` on the line `var handler = Plaid.create({`  Essentially, the frontend code needs the `Plaid` object from the link-initialize script; the `Plaid` object provided by the node package is not the right object.

Comment: Gotcha. You've probably installed the NodeJS server API. You can still wire up your frontend but it will require a bit more effort.

Answer (score 0):

I think the frontend library is called "Link"

I found in the Link docs this sentence:

https://plaid.com/docs/link/web/

> "It must always be loaded directly from https://cdn.plaid.com, rather than included in a bundle or hosted yourself."

The Plaid support team also got back to me and said they don't support or have a Node-based package for Link.